# Unable to use SerialDevice.ReadTimeout in Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, serial-port, timeout, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to implement a ModBus master on Windows 10 IoT on a Raspberry Pi 2.
I'm using an external **USB to RS-232** adapter since the internal serial port is reserved for Kernel Debugging.

Serial port is working. My question is mainly about timeout when reading.

Here is my code:

```
// Initialization
serialDevice.ReadTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, allowedTimeBetweenBytes);
serialDataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

// Reading
uint bytesRead = await serialDataReader.LoadAsync(MaxBufferSize); // 256
// Now use ReadBytes to get actual bytes
```

With no bytes awailable at the serial port RX input, I'm expecting the LoadAsync method to return 0 after wait. Unfortunately, it never returns. (Ok, it DOES return after 256 bytes are received, but that is not what I want)

Since ModBus intensively uses timeouts, I am not sure how to implement it. I am not even sure I could do it...

Does anyone already used timeouts on Windows 10 IoT serial ports?

Comment: Well, clearly InputStreamOptions.Partial is not working.  So roll the dice and try InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead and None next.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I couldn't get this working either. I'm not sure where `ReadTimeout` is actually used by the `SerialDevice` class internally. But I did end up getting something working by copying the timeout to a `CancellationTokenSource`.

You can see it in use in the following example I wrote for an old serial Mettler Toledo PS 60 shipping scale, where `device` is an instance of [`SerialDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.aspx). Seems to work in my case, at least.

```
using (var writer = new DataWriter(device.OutputStream))
{
    writer.WriteString("W\r\n");

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(device.WriteTimeout))
    {
        await writer.StoreAsync().AsTask(cts.Token);
    }

    writer.DetachStream();
}

using (var reader = new DataReader(device.InputStream))
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(device.ReadTimeout))
    {
        var read = await reader.LoadAsync(12).AsTask(cts.Token);

        if (read >= 12)
        {
            var data = reader.ReadString(12);
            reader.DetachStream();

            return ExtractWeightChangedEventArgs(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I used a similar code and it works fine for me too! At least we now have a way to read bytes with a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a couple weeks fighting this and doing testing.

1. ReadTimeout has no effect on the first byte of a read call. Read calls always wait forever for the first byte.
2. ReadTimeout = 0ms causes read calls to wait forever for all subsequent bytes requested on a multi-byte read call.
3. ReadTimeout = Greater than 0ms causes read calls to timeout after that time when waiting for any subsequent bytes after the first.
4. ReadTimeout is a TimeSpan, which means the caller can specify a timeout value with more resolution than milliseconds. However, the underlying Windows calls only have a millisecond resolution.
5. My experiments using a CancellationTokenSource with a timeout value seemed to result in the SerialDevice object becoming unstable after a timeout cancellation.

I ended up creating a class derived from SerialDevice. The derived class launched a background task which simply issued read requests to the base SerialDevice class and stored the returned data in a queue.  I set ReadTimeout to 1ms so my background task could issue large read requests, but then receive and store data into the queue as the data became available without waiting for the entire request.

I created a circular queue for memory efficiency. .NET does not provide one standard. When dealing with high baud rates, copying read data to the queue will need to be very efficient. Meaning copying blocks of data. Not messing around with the data byte by byte.

The derived class provided alternate read methods which would return data from the queue and could return immediately if no data was in the queue.

With the SerialDevice reads occurring in the background task there was never any need to cancel the read requests and risk destabilize SerialDevice. The reads only had a CancellationToken for when the background task was being signaled to terminate because the derived class was closing SerialDevice and disposing.