# Why does DataWriter.StoreAsync() not timeout in Windoes IOT Core like it does in Desktop UWP?

Tags: serial-port, windows-iot-core-10

I have an issue with a UWP app targeted to run on Windows IOT Core (Raspberry Pi 3) that doesn't behave in the same manner as it does in Windows Desktop.

Basically my app has a list of strings that it pushes out the RS-232 serial port one at a time.  Hardware handshaking is implemented to control the flow by the destination device.  My code is based around something like this:

```
myDataWriter.WriteString(myStringList[i]);
uint x = await PortDataWriter.StoreAsync();
```

If x > 0 then I increment my index pointer (i) and continue looping through the list of strings I want to send.  If x is not > 0 I don't increment my index pointer, and I try the same string over again.

My issue happens when the UART buffer fills up due to the hardware handshaking RTS being low.

In Windows Desktop the StoreAsync() will time out based on the .WriteTimeout parameter in the SerialDevice, return a 0 and allow me to react appropriately.

In IOT Core however, the StoreAsync() never times out, and will even lock up the entire OS and cause a blue screen watchdog violation after a while.

Can anybody shed some light on this or maybe provide some advice on how to properly react to hardware handshaking circumstances that lead to the UART buffer filling up?  I need to be able to react to long periods of RTS low in the middle of my loop (say an hour in some cases) and be able to break out of the loop on command if the user chooses.

Example:

https://github.com/MyersMade/PiSerialCrashTest

Thanks

Comment: I have even tried:                

PortDataWriter.WriteString(s);

                //uint x = await PortDataWriter.StoreAsync(); ---Removed---

                try
                {
                    Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;
                    storeAsyncTask = PortDataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask();
                    x = await storeAsyncTask;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

Comment: You can reference [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157918/unable-to-use-serialdevice-readtimeout-in-windows-10-iot) and use CancellationTokenSource(device.WriteTimeout).

Comment: I tried this based on what Rita sent: edited

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(Port.WriteTimeout))
    {
        x = await PortDataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask(cts.Token);
    }

It stopped the bluescreen, but still hangs the app when the UART buffer gets full due to handshaking.

Comment: Do you use the mini UART port([pin8 and pin10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/pinmappingsrpi)) or USB port(USB to TTL) on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I am using a USB to RS-232 adapter (FTDI chipset). It shows up as FT232R USB UART.  I've provided sample code and a better description on GitHub: https://github.com/MyersMade/PiSerialCrashTest/  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's value of the `Port.IsRequestToSendEnabled`?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT ,

`Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;`
`storeAsyncTask = PortDataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask();`
`Debug.WriteLine(Port.IsRequestToSendEnabled);`
`uint x = await storeAsyncTask;`

Always returns true on both the Pi and the Windows Desktop environment.

Comment: I have also verified that the RTS on the target RS-232 device (CTS on Source(Pi) Device) IS actually changing state as expected by the indicator LED's on the adapters.

Comment: Can you detect the CTS pin value changed event by serialPort.PinChanged on Desktop? What about on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I'm gonna need some advice on how to test that. ???

Comment: When you config the serial device settings you can register the event like this:`Port.PinChanged += pinChanged;` and in the event handler you can check which pin's value changed like this:`private void pinChanged(SerialDevice serialdevice, PinChangedEventArgs pin)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("which pin changed:" + pin.PinChange.ToString());
        }`

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes it fires the event

Comment: Ok, it looks like not work on Raspberry Pi with Windows iot core. You can [open an issue on github](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/issues).

Comment: ok, will do.  thank you @RitaHan-MSFT